# Running total but add previous row with a constant instead of current row

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a table like below with some initial values:

| date | value | constant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | 10 | 0.25 |
| 2020-03-01 |  | 0.25 |
| 2020-04-01 |  | 0.50 |
| 2020-05-01 |  | 0.25 |
| 2020-06-01 |  | 0 |

I'm looking for the output to be as below:

| date | new_value | constant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | 10 | 0.25 |
| 2020-03-01 | 10.25 | 0.25 |
| 2020-04-01 | 10.50 | 0.50 |
| 2020-05-01 | 11.0 | 0.25 |
| 2020-06-01 | 11.25 | 0 |

It's like a running total but I don't want to add previous row value but a value in another column instead. Any idea how I can implement this?

Comment: What happens if you have another value follows by `NULL`s?

Comment: my dataset doesn't but afaik, the window frames should be specified to match the use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can handle this using `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(value) OVER (ORDER BY date) +
    SUM(constant) OVER (ORDER BY date
                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS new_value,
    constant
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: thanks for the response! this worked. I just had to add a PARTITION BY clause to reset the sum by groups, but this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function `sum` as follows:

```
select date,
       sum(coalesce(value,0) + constant) over (order by date) as constant
  from t;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I think the constant column will not pick the previous row value unless ROWS BETWEEN clause is specified.

Comment: It will take them into consideration or use another column like id with it